# How put API key on env files in a Node.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, http-headers

This is my first time I'm trying to handle "Web API", so I took [this project](https://github.com/codebubb/job-search-app) to get many call but after it running well, when I try to click to "search" it doesn't work.
I guess the problem arises from API call because Chrome inspector show me this:

[image]

I was able to understand on the different forums, for handling APIs call with Node.js that must be encapsulated API calls behind "Environment variable".

That the **config.js** file:

[image]

When I try to put on the terminal `export env.API_KEY='000000000000000'` it made me:

> export: not valid in this context: env.API_KEY

I hope you can point me in the right direction, I very tried everything, to run it that.

Comment: If you are exporting through the terminal don’t do env.API_KEY just do API_KEY

Comment: @about14sheep yea i put `export APP_ID='0000000'` on the terminal, but still dosent working

Comment: remove the quotes

Answer (score 2):

I personally like to use a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) called `dotenv`:

You can install it by running `npm i dotenv` within your api directory.

Have a file called `.env` within your api directory which contains all of your environment variables:

```
APP_ID="000000000000000"
API_KEY="000000000000000"
```

Then change `config.js` to load all environment variable files when it is executed by including `require('dotenv').config()`:

```
require('dotenv').config()
module.exports = {
  APP_ID: process.env.APP_ID,
  API_KEY: process.env.API_KEY,
  BASE_URL: 'https://api.adzuna.com/v1/api/jobs',
  BASE_PARAMS: 'search/1?&results_per_page=20&content-type=application/json',
};
```

Note: you will also want to add `.env` to your `.gitingore` so that your sensitive API keys aren't included in your git repository

Comment: I did exactly that, but i have still same error

Answer (score -1):

actually OPENAI_API_KEY= works inside the .env file without quotations for me, but as Matt Davis said add a .gitignore to avoid mishaps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35405747)